# Fullcalendar auto refresh if db changes

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

### I'm developing app using Fullcalendar v1.

I successfully integrate connection to mysql database so my events are loaded from db as json array. But my app are going to use more than 2 people in one moment so i need automatically refresh after my db changes. If one user remove event, calendar refresh for all other users which see this calendar.

I have one experimenting script which i made. It works but not as well as i want. 
I know, this script is completely bad but i was frustrated.

```
<script>
var i = setInterval(function(){
last_id = $.cookie('last_id');

$.get("foo.php", function(data) {
       var id = data;


 if(last_id !== id) {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents');



last_id = $.cookie('last_id', data);
 }

 });
},500);
</script>
```

It works pretty simple ... **foo.php** loads number of rows. If this number is other than last number saved in cookies, calendar will be refreshed.

This method has tons of disadvantages and mistakes. It works only for deleting and creating events. Not for moving etc. And it is slowing app by getting results every 500ms ..

Have you better solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar structure.. get data from DB as JSON...

I make a modal for change a event...

When i press the button who calls my db to update the event..

I use behind... a function on jQuery called ( .trigger('click') ) so..

```
 $('.fc-prev-button').trigger('click');
 $('.fc-next-button').trigger('click');
  //Hide Modal.. button have a data-dismiss="modal"
 $('#closeEdit').trigger('click');
```

That's my solutions because when load fullCalendar this call events.. param who get data from my db... so when you change the month this is called again for reload the data and don't load the full month with data..

Sorry for my english and i hope to help you, Happy Coding !!